# app crashing while calling number by using SIP

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sip

I am doing iOS app which supports calling to numbers (mobile and landlines). Regarding this feature i integrated SIP (Session Initiate Protocol). Its working good. But sometimes while calling time my app getting crashing in following line

```
status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id);
```

and the above line initiated in following method:

```
pj_status_t sip_dial_with_uri(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, const char *uri, pjsua_call_id *call_id)
{

 pj_status_t status = PJ_SUCCESS;
    pj_str_t pj_uri;

 PJ_LOG(5,(THIS_FILE,  "Calling URI \"%s\".", uri));

status = pjsua_verify_sip_url(uri);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
{
    PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE,  "Invalid URL \"%s\".", uri));
    pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Invalid URL", status);
    return status;
}
  pj_uri = pj_str((char *)uri);

NSLog(@"***check point for assert, acc_id:%d, uri:%s, call_id:%d", (int)acc_id, uri, *call_id);
status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id);

if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
{
    pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error making call", status);
}
return status;
}
```

if anyone used this API sofar, please provide your valuable suggestions!! Thanks

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: hi @DROPPY STACKTRACE? i dint get you

Comment: The error message and the trace that indicates the line of your program where the crash occurs.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your quick response!! but i am having poor knowledge about SIP and i searched most of websites regarding this issue, but not got helped information!

Comment: We can't begin to help you without more information - the exception message and the stack trace

Comment: i never used this api previous and i have strucked over here

Comment: @Anilkumar add exception break point https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq4o7vdldrsyhge/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2011.55.50%20am.png?dl=0

Comment: and let us know where it crashing

Comment: @Jageen as you said, i gone that way and its again crashing in the line  status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id); and showing Signal SIGBART

Comment: @Anilkumar it's new thing for me too if possible share project i will do some R&D and make it work

Comment: @Jageen thanks for your help sofar, but my project is very big!! i cant share total project brother

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66746/discussion-between-anilkumar-and-jageen).